# Get all claimed & unclaimed items for a group in Activiti

Tags: activiti

How can I query all items claimed/unclaimed by user which belongs to a particular group? So I want to build an API of below format
List getAllTasks4Group(String group)

The reason why I want this API is I don't have know all the users which might have acquired tasks and all these tasks belong to same group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `TaskQuery`'s `candidateGroup` method only returns unclaimed tasks, the easiest way I know to do this is to use a [native query](http://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/TaskService.html#createNativeTaskQuery%28%29):

```
String groupId = ...

String taskTable = managementService.getTableName(TaskEntity.class);
String identityLinkTable = managementService.getTableName(IdentityLinkEntity.class);

List<Task> groupTasks = taskService.createNativeTaskQuery()
        .sql("select _TASK.*" +
             "  from " + taskTable + " _TASK" +
             "  join " + identityLinkTable + " _LINK on _TASK.ID_ = _LINK.TASK_ID_" +
             " where _LINK.TYPE_ = 'candidate'" +
             "   and _LINK.GROUP_ID_ = #{groupId}")
        .parameter("groupId", groupId)
        .list();
```

Comment: can i use REST API to get tasks using groupId or userId

Answer (score 1):

You can UserQuery for getting all users of a group:

> **UserQuery [memberOfGroup](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/identity/UserQuery.html#memberOfGroup%28java.lang.String%29)(String groupId)**
>
> Only select Users that belong to the given group.

And then iterate over the users for collecting the tasks with TaskQuery:

> **TaskQuery [taskAssignee](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/identity/UserQuery.html#memberOfGroup%28java.lang.String%29)(String assignee)**
>
> Only select tasks which are assigned to the given user.

There are also direct queries for candidate [users](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/task/TaskQuery.html#taskCandidateUser%28java.lang.String%29) / [groups](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/identity/UserQuery.html#memberOfGroup%28java.lang.String%29) mentioned in the Javadocs.

Comment: Btw, I am not using identity schema of Activiti and there by user query cannot be used in my case.